# Apply watermark on pdf stored in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any way to apply watermark across a pdf stored in google drive. I couldn't find anything, which can be done through google appscript.

Any ideas will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Heres one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220133/google-spreadsheet-to-pdf-with-watermark-in-google-script -- Here's another link: http://alicekeeler.com/2014/09/10/create-a-background-image-or-watermark-on-a-google-doc/  There are some other way just google them.  Most links are pretty old.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work on a PDF, but I've put a watermark in to a Gmail email.  Which I did with HTML, and I also create PDF's using HTML, so it might work.  Actually, I just updated an answer about a watermark using HTML in SO Answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/67013138/2946873](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67013138/2946873)

Comment: I want the original pdf to have the watermark, rather than making it on the HTML side. Is there a way to do that by using any free third party pdf tools? It should have the watermark when I print also